# Fatal error: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, mysql

Haciendo un login con php y mysql me salta este error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajofinal\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajofinal\index.php(11): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajofinal\index.php on line 11. Busque por internet, pero ninguno pudo solucionar mi problema. Este es el código:

```
if (!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['contrasenia'])){
$records = $conexion->prepare('SELECT id, contrasenia, nombre, apellido FROM usuarios WHERE nombre=:usuario');
$records->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['usuario']);
$records->execute();
$results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$message = '';

if (count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['contrasenia'], $results['contrasenia'])) {
$_SESSION['id'] = $results['id'];
header('Location: inicio.php');
} else {
$message = 'Datos ingresados no coinciden';
}
}
```

Comment: Por favor, por el mensaje de error COMPLETO dentro de la pregunta, yendo a [edit]. :)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.